# Detect deletion of all contacts in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

If User is clearing data of native contact storage app from setting then how can I detect that thing in my android application?

Is there any intent that is sent?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any intent will be triggered while clearing data of native contact app. But you can add `content observer` in your app, which will notify your app on any contact modification(add/delete/update).

Refer,
[Content Observer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)

Here is the code snippet,

```
    private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public MyContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }

    }

    MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver();

     // Registers content observer
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, false, contentObserver);
```

Comment: But how can I know if all the contacts are cleared at once?